# Embed Marketo Web to PDF

Tags: forms, pdf, embed, marketo

A client has asked for our design team to embed a Marketo form into a Interactive PDF.

I've advised against it as:

1. I don't know it's possible ( They've claimed it is )
2. It's a bit pointless added forms to pdf's when they have a website and app both with forms...

So anyway, even being advised against it, they are detemined that want this form embedding in the PDF.

Does anyone have any ideas? The embed code ( Client sent me - Claims this is to work in PDF's )

```
<script src="//pages.name.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_00000"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//pages.name.com", "000-XMS-000", 00000);</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As described, this isn't possible. However, instead of embedding the form in the PDF, you can display the PDF in a browser using the free Adobe Embed API. You can then use any number of events while the user is navigating the PDF to trigger the display the Marketo form. For example, if the PDF is 10 pages long and they want the form to pop up when the user scrolls past page 3, you can do that. The other advantage of Embed API is that you control the PDF experience so it displays exactly the same way regardless of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible... at least not embedded in a PDF. The JavaScript interpreter in Acrobat and other JavaScript-capable viewers do not use the HTML object model. It uses the JavaScript core and an object model specific to PDF. However, see my comment for another option.